# Stored procedure output parameter always gives 0 in PHP end

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

The Stored Procedure is tested from MS SQL Server and gave expected output (for @AID). But when it is called from PHP @AID always gives 0. What am I doing wrong here?

```
$stmt = mssql_init('UpdateActivity2', $conn);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@ParentActivity', $PP_ActivityID, SQLINT4, false, false, 8);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@ActivityName', $activityName, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 255);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@ActivityType', $activityType, SQLINT4, false, false, 4);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@ActivityStatus', $activityStatus, SQLINT4, false, false,4);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@Descr', $descr, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 255);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@RegistrationDate', $now, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 255);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@FinishDate', $now, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 255);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@Owner', $owner, SQLINT4, false, false, 4);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@SourceID', $sourceID, SQLINT4, false, false, 4);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@ContactID', $c, SQLINT4, false, false, 4);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@ActivityAddress',$a, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 255);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@ExtReference', $e, SQLVARCHAR, false, false, 255);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@ResponsibleCompanyID', $e, SQLINT4, false, false, 4);
mssql_bind($stmt, '@AID', $h, SQLINT4, true);
$proc_result = mssql_execute($stmt);
echo $h;
```

@AID is the output parameter on the stored procedure. But, $h gives 0 always.
Here's the SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UpdateActivity2]
@ParentActivity int,
@ActivityName varchar(150),
@ActivityType int,
@ActivityStatus int,
@Descr varchar(1024),
@RegistrationDate datetime,
@FinishDate datetime,
@Owner int,
@SourceID int,
@ContactID int,
@ActivityAddress varchar(150),
@ExtReference varchar(50),
@ResponsibleCompanyID int,
@AID int OUTPUT
AS
DECLARE @Value int;
EXEC @Value =  PG_GetSeq @Name = 'Activity'
PRINT('Printing')
PRINT(@Value)
INSERT INTO Activity(
                ActivityID, 
                ParentActivity, 
                ActivityName, 
                ActivityType, 
                ActivityStatus, 
                Descr, 
                RegistrationDate, 
                FinishDate, 
                Owner, 
                SourceID, 
                ContactID, 
                ActivityAddress, 
                ExtReference, 
                ResponsibleCompanyID
            )
            VALUES(
                @Value, 
                @ParentActivity, 
                @ActivityName, 
                @ActivityType, 
                @ActivityStatus, 
                @Descr, 
                @RegistrationDate, 
                @FinishDate, 
                @Owner, 
                @SourceID, 
                @ContactID, 
                @ActivityAddress, 
                @ExtReference, 
                @ResponsibleCompanyID
            )

    SELECT @AID = ActivityID FROM Activity WHERE ActivityID = @Value
```

Insert statement gets the correct value for @Value and the row is inserted correctly too.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-execute.php)

> If the stored procedure returns parameters or a return value these will be available after the call to mssql_execute() unless the stored procedure returns more than one result set. In that case use mssql_next_result() to shift through the results. When the last result has been processed the output parameters and return values will be available.

Your print statements (and likely row counts too) are interfering with the result sets, so it appears as though you have more than one, therefore you need to call `mssql_next_result()` until it returns false then you will have access to the output parameters.

Alternatively you can pass `true` for the parameter `$skip_results`:

```
mssql_execute($stmt, false);
```

This gives you immediate access to the output parameters.